# parent disappear when add a child component in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a strange problem. When I try to render a component ("parent"), it works fine. but, when I add a child component, I cant see both components on screen (parent&child). My code looks like :

Does not Work:

```html
import React from 'react';
import SonComp from './SonComp';

export default class ParentBox extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    <SonComp />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Does Work:

```html
import React from 'react';

export default class ParentBox extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    <p>Hello<p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The child :

```html
import React from 'react';

export default class SonComp extends React.component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>hi</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the `React.component` in your does not work code to `React.Component`.